# Updating part of page with prototype and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

i work with page using prototype, and i have to add some ajax requests, which updates content of one specified div.
Here how i did it in jquery:

```
$j.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (result) {
        var resultDiv = $j(result).find('.SOME-CLASS');
        $j('.SOME-CLASS').html(resultDiv.html());
    }
});
```

I tried to get the same result with prototype for last few hours and finaly i gave up. How would it look in prototype ? Its important to withdraw from result div with class SOME-CLASS and replace its content with existing in document div with the same class.

PS.
I thought about parsing raw result string recived from prototypes request to get content of  and then replace founded content with existing in document, but in my opinion this is bad, non elegant solution. Is there anything better ? I heard that prototype is great tool for DOM manipulation.

Comment: I find Prototype is merely _good_ at DOM manipulation but _great_ at data manipulation. jQuery is famously great at DOM manipulation but infamously poor at anything else. That works just fine since most web designers have no further needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        var html = new Element('div');
        html.update(response.responseText);
        // There may be many .SOME-CLASS so use `invoke` to iterate through them
        $$('.SOME-CLASS').invoke('update', html.select('.SOME-CLASS').first());
    }
});
```

Prototype doesn't have an equivalent to jQuery's `$(htmlString)` shortcut, so you'll have to assign the HTML string to a newly created element then extract the child classes back (which is how jQuery does it behind the scenes). The temporary element is never added to the DOM so isn't seen directly.

When searching for the incoming element by it's class we must use [`Element.select`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/) which returns an array. If we assume there will be only one match, or are only interested in one match, the first element of that array is used. Perhaps this isn't what you wanted and meant to collect multiple elements from the response. That is an ambiguity caused by using class names instead of IDs.

Here is [a demonstration fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkMyZ/).

Comment: Yea, this is almost working. However it doesn't replace contents of div.SOME-CLASS but it puts whole div from response into div in document (with <div> tag), so it needs to insert innerHTML attribute, not whole selector.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you have this:

```
<form id='myForm'>
.... fields ....
<input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Your js would be, more or less:

```
Event.observe('myForm', 'submit', function(event) {
    $('myForm').request({
        onFailure: function() { .... },
        onSuccess: function(t) {
            $('result').update(t.responseText);
        }
    });
    Event.stop(event); // stop the form from submitting
});
```

Comment: 1. I didnt mention about any form. 2. I have div with specified class, not id. 3. I dont want to replace this div with whole response. And 4 ... if i had situation such as you describe, i would use Ajax.Updater rather than your way.

Answer (score 0):

to update the contents of specified div using protoype on success ajax response:

```
var container = $$(".yourdiv")[0]; //div class as it returns array so we used the index
container.update(response.responseText);
```

i have tested this and it works perfectly.